# Searching for a specific value in XML-File using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath

I have a little problem:

I have this XML-File:

```
<response>
    <game_count>768</game_count>
    <games>
        <message>
            <appid>730</appid>
            <playtime_forever>549</playtime_forever>
        </message>
        <message>
            <appid>1300</appid>
            <playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
        </message>
        <message>
            <appid>1309</appid>
....
```

I tried to search for the value `appid == '730'` but unfortunately nothing helped.

E.G i tried this:

```
$game = new SimpleXMLElement($account_game_data);
$res = $game->xpath("games/message/appid[. = 730]");
print_r($res);
```

My result should be `<appid>730</appid><playtime_forever>549</playtime_forever></message>` as `SimpleXMLElement`.

If there is any code required, I will post it.

Comment: in your final result the sibling tag is also captured, should it be so?

Comment: @RomanPerekhres It works very fine. At least i had one fault, which isn't regarding to your code. It causes, that the `game`-var was empty. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
$game = new \SimpleXMLElement($account_game_data);
$res = $game->xpath('games/message[appid="730"]');
print_r($res[0]->asXML());
```

The output:

```
<message>
            <appid>730</appid>
            <playtime_forever>549</playtime_forever>
        </message>
```

---

`message[appid="730"]` - matches the `message` element which has child `appid` with value `730`

Comment: instead of selecting the parent with `..`, you can put the end of the path in the predicate: `games/message[appid="730"]`. You can even select the children of the first "message" that matches: `games/message[appid="730"][1]/*` *( then you have to loop over them to display them with `SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`)*

Comment: Strange, I don't have this problem: https://eval.in/755883 (perhaps take care of the quotes I used).

Comment: You need to remove the slash before the predicate.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, that's enough for me today(GMT +02:00. late night). Your suggestion is correct. I've updated to your expression. Thanks